# Penetrating exterior wall to bring in a continuous MC cable to the garage

Tags: electrical, wiring, exterior, electric-vehicle

I'm installing a high current 100 amp EV charger inside my garage.  It seems easiest to wire it with a continuous run of 2/3 MC cable from the outdoor breaker panel, first strapped to the exterior wall, then run through some sort of conduit body for weather protection, and then into the garage.  The wires inside the cable are rated for wet, so I believe outdoor use of MC under eaves would meet code.  But how can I get it through the wall without cutting and re-connecting the large AWG2 wires?  The cable is 1.18" OD. I'm thinking of running it through a 1.25 inch PVC or EMT conduit body.  But since the metal cladding won't make a 90 degree turn in less than about 7 inches, I would either have to terminate the cladding at the body, or cut away the body back to allow an angled smooth curve into the wall.  What is the right way to do it?

Comment: What is the manufacturer’s requirement on the charger I have installed quite a few even commercial ones and never have needed a 100 amp circuit yet. Most of the big ones are 70a (well I guess I should state that was 480v 3 phase so much more power than 240v 100amp commercial charger.

Comment: So much good info so far.  Yes most of the assumptions are right:  This is a Tesla HPWC runs max 80A, on a 100A breaker.  I did aluminum before but it kept me up at night, even though I did all the grease and proper brushing away of oxidation at the ends before, I  know Al expands with heat and needs to be re-compressed eventually or will heat up and can cause a fire.  So I was planning for expensive (and heavy) #2 or #3 copper wire.  Planning to use 2/3  or 3/3 to include neutral because I eventually think there will be an RV box next to the EV charger.

Comment: If you go with metal clad and want to cut the cladding you will have to use a box. Yes some conduit bodies are stamped with there size in cubic inches but they are not large enough to splice that size wire so a box and nipple are the normal choice. 
As for the L’s they always show them in photos like a 7 so they look backwards but if you flip them over like a L or a backwards L the hole comes out on the left when hooking at the opening  or a LR the opening on the right and you as most folks have figured out the LB going out the back.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Myself, I'd use metal conduit, because  *conduit bodies* can make pretty sharp turns. See [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/186342/back-to-back-conduit-bodies-for-wall-transition). Since you're already sure a big metal snake will handle most of your bends, I'd just use FMC (Flexible Metal Conduit) between conduit bodies.

[image]

[image]

In conduit, you run individual wires.  This is less stiff (like how a ream of copier paper is less stiff after you unwrap it), and so it has no trouble getting around conduit body corners.  (it can't be *pulled around* those corners, but that's why conduit bodies have access covers).

1-1/4" FMC will handle three #1 wires + a #4 or smaller ground.  That covers your need today, with expansion options (either by eliminating neutral, or switching to copper).

Check, but most likely your 100A EVSE **does not need neutral**.  Don't run neutral if you don't need it.  Beauty of conduit is, *you can always add it later*.

Whenever wires are larger than #6, you don't need to follow color coding rules but do need to mark them with "phase tape" - white or gray for neutral, green or yellow/green for grounds.

Your 100A ground can be #6 Al or #8 Cu, but at those sizes no remarking (with individual wires) -- they'll need to be *natively* the correct color insulation (or bare if copper). The metal conduit shell *does not* work as ground - if you want that, use non-flex conduit such as EMT.

---

Look at your EVSE's nameplate, but I'm fairly sure your "100A EV charger" is actually an EVSE charging at 80A.  The 100A is arrived at because of the 125% derate called out in NEC 625.14. This means you need to wire it for 100A.

#2 is too small for 100A.  This is a common misconception because *it would be true* if you could apply 310.15(B)(7), *but you can't*.  They need to take it back.

You need #1 aluminum or #3 copper.  Aluminum has always been fine for large feeders like this, plus it'll be  the new AA-8000 alloy.  You don't need a wire size "bump" unless you are going farther than 175'.  (remember it actually draws 80A so calculate voltage drop based on that).

By the way, if the EVSE is listed for copper wires only, you can run aluminum and splice to a short copper wire. The cheapest way to make such a splice is to *install a subpanel*.  This takes care of all the splice blocks *and* provides a listed enclosure *and* gives other benefits.  E.G. if the next homeowner wants to support a smaller EVSE *and a welder*, they can do that.

Comment: Now I'm confused on how `LB` and `LL` got their names. `LB` I get - "ell, entrance on  back", but the `LR` seems to be an "ell, entrance on left" and the `LL` seems to be "ell, entrance on right". Unless those labels are incorrect...

Comment: @FreeMan I think they are assuming the pipe comes through the wall and then goes **up**.   I could be wrong, I can never get them straight lol.

Comment: The color coding rules for multi conductor cables has changed the size is exempted in 2020. I do not know why they left the wording in but multiconductor of any size can be re identified , not true with individual conductor pulled in a wireway.

Comment: @EdBeal I was in the context of individual wires, didn't make that clear.  Edited.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t cut the cladding.

Cut an elongated hole long enough to enter and continue on the other side of the wall. Start your cut right after a stud punch the inside hole so the cable will make a lazy Z. Pull the cable through the 2 holes and seal the outside one with a paintable silicone calking.

If you want a 90 yes cut the cladding but the problem then is having enough space to splice the #2 wire this will probably take a box and fittings, this can get expensive box on the outside, nipple box inside, or a large box through the wall.

I have done both and any time I can eliminate a splice I will opt for that especially on high amperage feeders.

The sealing is not that difficult  and whatever method is used will require some sealing.

I would use a 1–1/8 or 1-1/4” hole saw drill the first hole then as close as (overlapping about 1/2) possible drill the second hole so the length is about ~2” the same thing inside at the other side of the stud bay works best (less possibility of breaking Sheetrock

A clamp can be put on each side just prior to entering the wall. No extra connectors, boxes or wire nuts needed.
14” is plenty of space to make the lazy Z from one side to the other.

Comment: Voice of experience.+